# SQL Server 2012: Column names into result values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a dynamic pivot that returns table with changing columns (once there are 2 columns, other time can be 5. I need to include table column names into result values like in the below example. How can I do it?

```
SELECT
    'John' AS Name,
    'Malkovich' AS Surname 
INTO #T
```

Result table should have 'Name' and 'Surname' as values

```
Name, Surname (column names)
Name, Surname,
John, Malkovich
```

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: `union all select 'Name', 'Surname'` ?

Comment: Hi Lashane, forgot to mention - table comes from a dynamic pivot table - I can't hard code the names into select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to union the column names to your pivot. For example:

```
declare @colNamesFormattedForSelect VARCHAR(MAX)
set @colNamesFormattedForSelect = '''Name'' as Name, ''Surname'' as Surname' 
-- create this value dynamically for your pivot (glhf)

set @sql = 'SELECT ' + @colNamesFormattedForSelect + 
           'UNION ALL ' + 
           -- Your pivot here
```

Of course all of your columns need to be able to take text for this to work.

I really would suggest re-examining your use case to see if there is a better solution than this. In most scenarios there are better ways to access the column name.